# Loop to perform same upsampling task over several pandas dataframes for logistic regression

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I have a series of dataframes containing daily rainfall totals (continuous data) and whether or not a flood occurs (binary data, i.e. 1 or 0). Each data frame represents a year (e.g. df01, df02, df03, etc.), which looks like this:

```
date        ppt    fld
01/02/2011  1.5    0
02/02/2011  0.0    0
03/02/2011  2.7    0
04/02/2011  4.6    0
05/02/2011  15.5   1
06/02/2011  1.5    0
...
```

I wish to perform logistic regression on each year of data, but the data is heavily imbalanced due to the very small number of flood events relative to  the number of rainfall events. As such, I wish to upsample just the minority class (values of 1 in 'fld'). So far I know to split each dataframe into two according to the 'fld' value, upsample the resulting '1' dataframe, and then remerge into one dataframe.

```
# So if I apply to one dataframe it looks like this:

# Separate majority and minority classes
mask = df01.fld == 0
fld_0 = df01[mask]
fld_1 = df01[~mask]

# Upsample minority class
fld_1_upsampled = resample(fld_1, 
                                 replace=True,     # sample with replacement
                                 n_samples=247,    # to match majority class
                                 random_state=123) # reproducible results

# Combine majority class with upsampled minority class
df01_upsampled = pd.concat([fld_0, fld_1_upsampled])
```

As I have 17 dataframes, it is inefficient to go dataframe-by-dataframe. Are there any thoughts as to how I could be more efficient with this? So far I have tried this (it is probably evident I have no idea what I am doing with loops of this kind, I am quite new to python):

```
df_all = [df01, df02, df03, df04,
           df05, df06, df07, df08, 
           df09, df10, df11, df12, 
           df13, df14, df15, df16, df17]
# This is my list of annual data

for i in df_all:
fld_0 = i[mask]
fld_1 = i[~mask]

    fld_1_upsampled = resample(fld_1, 
                               replace=True,     # sample with replacement
                               n_samples=len(fld_0),    # to match majority class
                               random_state=123) # reproducible results
    i_upsampled = pd.concat([fld_0, fld_1_upsampled])
return i_upsampled
```

Which returns the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-6fd782d4c469> in <module>()
     11                                replace=True,     # sample with replacement
     12                                n_samples=247,    # to match majority class
---> 13                                random_state=123) # reproducible results
     14     i_upsampled = pd.concat([fld_0, fld_1_upsampled])
     15 return i_upsampled

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py in resample(*arrays, **options)
    259 
    260     if replace:
--> 261         indices = random_state.randint(0, n_samples, size=(max_n_samples,))
    262     else:
    263         indices = np.arange(n_samples)

mtrand.pyx in mtrand.RandomState.randint()

ValueError: low >= high
```

Any advice or comments greatly appreciated :)

UPDATE: one reply suggested that some of my dataframes may not contain any samples from the minority class. This was correct, so I have removed them, but the same error arises.

Answer (score 0):

Giving you the benefit of the doubt that you're using the same `mask` syntax in your second code block as in your first, it looks like you may not have any samples to pass in to your `resample` in one or more of your DFs:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'date':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'ppt':[1.5,0,2.7,4.6,15.5,1.5],'fld':[0,1,0,0,1,1]})

date    ppt     fld
1       1.5     0
2       0.0     1
3       2.7     0
4       4.6     0
5       15.5    1
6       1.5     1

resample(df[df.fld==1], replace=True, n_samples=3, random_state=123)

date    ppt     fld
6       1.5     1
5       15.5    1
6       1.5     1

resample(df[df.fld==2], replace=True, n_samples=3, random_state=123)

"...ValueError: low >= high"
```